# How to calculate the feedack resistor in this configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting

I try to simulate the input stage of the ADC feeding circuit. ADC is 0-3.3V.

The circuit:
[image]

The Vin input signal:
[image]

The output:
[image]

The signal is shifted properly but the gain is lower than I expected. 
My question is how to properly calculate the value of the R12.

Comment: Don't  you also want to avoid phase shift ? and block signals above 1/2 sampling rate by xx dB and get Av=33 flat to 10 kHz . what is conversion rate?

Comment: Also what is your DC offset budget and Vref tolerance?  (?-4.7V) you should use the 3.3V as offset Vref,  same as ADC??

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Actually Voffset was left by mistake. `vpo` is the offset signal.  Vpo signal is amplified properly but the actual signal is not (it should be 0-3.3V). At this stage I do not care about the aliasing. Just try to figure out how to calculate the gain.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes Rs =~0 and if not then must be specified. All R's may be scaled up x10 and use 0.1%

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwVORr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rev A: Zin= 1M input //27pF ( LT1113)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fThTOV.png)</sup>

The advantage of using 3.3V if that is your ADc Vref is that offsets track 3.3V tolerance error, so no trimmers are needed unless you specify budget < R tolerance stackup.

Comment: Yes this way I know how to add the voltage shift. My one is complicated for the purpose. 1. The vps has to come from the voltage divider (actually it is a trimming resistor). 2. The gain can be changed - and I need to change the vpo as well. I need ~1M input resistance.

Comment: BTW I have this gain problem when gain is > 200. Can it be slew rate problem?

Comment: Of course the simulation circuit is simplified - as you see no capacitors, no input capacitance compensation - etc etc

Comment: GBW limits = gain * BW

Comment: But why the offset voltage is amplified properly. gain BW here is 5MHz and the signal is 10k. I do not do too much analog electronics and my knowledge is a bit rusty :).

Comment: 5M/33= 150kHz with phase starting to shift 1 decade down  5M/200=25kHz